# Is [How kind she is to take care of Tony!] correct?

Tags: exclamatives

I found a sentence in my grammar book for Junior high school students in Japanese as follows;

> How kind she is to take care of Tony!

The book explains that this sentence means ”she is so nice,
because she takes care of Tony.”

Please advise me the correct sentence.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to explain why you doubt your book. This will help respondents address your problem.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by _**correct**_. There is nothing wrong with the sentence given in your book. It is good, grammatical English. Please **[edit]** your question to tell us why you think it might not be "correct".

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that you're questioning this part:

> How kind she is

Yes, it is correct. (HOW + adjective/ adverb + Subject + Verb)

It is an interrogative clause serves as an exclamation. Look at these two sentences:

> It is far.

This phrase only states the fact that the object is far from the speaker.

> How far it is!

This phrase, however, insists on the "emotion" of the speaker against the distance.

Another example:

> "- Honey, I want to buy this car!"
>
> "- No, we can't, it's too expensive!"
>
> "- But look how beautiful it is!"